# Creating a contact form in the footer using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a contact form in the footer of my page so it's in my application view.

My Application controller looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  protected

  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
    name = params[:contact][:name]
    email = params[:contact][:email]
    body = params[:contact][:comments]
    ContactMailer.contact_email(name, email, body).deliver
    flash[:success] = 'Message sent.'
    redirect_to ""
  else
    flash[:success] = 'Error occured, message has not been sent.'
    redirect_to ""
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

  private
    def contact_params
      params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
    end

end
```

The partial view that I'm using currently looks like this in my application view:

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :comments %>
        <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

I'm sure there's something wrong with it but I'm unable to understand how the controllers and models are working together.

Comment: Please don't use salutations ("hi"), valedictions like "thanks" or signatures. SO isn't a discussion board, it's like a reference-book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your code between `protected` and `private` runs in the context of the class, so at the time when your application loads the file. It should throw an exception `undefined method or variable params for ApplicationController:Class`

You need to run it per request, so something like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  before_filter :set_contact

  private

  def set_contact
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

end
```

`before_filter` is a method which tells your controller what should it do before each request. You only need to set the `@contact` instance variable to display and bind the form, form however should submit to create action on `ContactsController`:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact.name, @contact.email, @contact.body).deliver
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent.'
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:success] = 'Error occurred, message has not been sent.'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
  end
end
```

One thing to notice is that `before_filter` will run before every single action, regardless of type of response (even for redirection, when you do not display anything). Obviously this is a waste which is why it is probably better to do the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
  helper_method :new_contact

  private

  def new_contact
    Contact.new
  end

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :stripe_card_token, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end   
end

#form

<%= form_for new_contact do %>
```

This way new contact is build in memory only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create a new controller for contacts:

```
# /app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb
class ContactsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    if @contact.save
      ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact.name, @contact.email, @contact.comments).deliver
      # Or you can send @contact object and find name, email etc. values in mailer
      # ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver
      flash[:success] = 'Message sent.'
      redirect_to ""
    else
      flash[:success] = 'Error occured, message has not been sent.'
      redirect_to ""
    end
  end

  private

  def contact_params
    params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
  end
end
```

And your form will go in `app/views/contacts/new.html.erb`. The footer link would be like:

```
<%= 'Contact Us', new_contact_path %>
```